# Java - Cannot convert to double

Tags: java, arraylist

When I try to get an item from an arraylist, it gives me an error saying

```
error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to double
       double highest = numbers.get(0);
```

and also this

```
error: bad operand types for binary operator '<'
        if(highest < numbers.get(i)){
```

I am new to java, but not programming, so I am not really sure what to do because the numbers **are** doubles (I have checked) but it still gives me an error when I try to select an item from the array or compare (`highest < numbers.get(i)`)

Here is the full code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
  public static void main (String[] args)throws IOException{
    boolean keepRunning = true;
    ArrayList numbers = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList sortedNumbers = new ArrayList();

    while(keepRunning){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Do you want to sort the numbers or add a number?");
        String answer = input.nextLine();

        if(answer.equals("sort")){
           double highest = numbers.get(0);
           for(int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++){
            if(highest < numbers.get(i)){
              highest = numbers.get(i);
            }
            System.out.print(numbers.get(i));
           }
          // System.out.println(highest);
           System.out.println("Bye Bye.");
           keepRunning = false;
        }else if(answer.equals("add")){
            System.out.print("What number to you want to add?");
            numbers.add(Double.parseDouble(input.nextLine()));
            System.out.println("Added number.");
        }else{
            System.out.println("That is not an option.");
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you did not use generics when constructing your list  `ArrayList numbers = new ArrayList();` the JVM will allow that list to contain any type of objects. Thus you need to include generics `ArrayList<Double> numbers = new ArrayList<Double>();` or cast when you  retrieve values from the list:

```
double highest = (double) numbers.get(0);
if(highest < (double) numbers.get(i)){
        highest = numbers.get(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When creating an ArrayList, you need to **identify the objectType** whether it be `Integer`, `String`, `Double`, or even **custom classes**.

```
ArrayList<ObjectType> list = new ArrayList<ObjectType>();

//In this case, the ObjectType is a double, so the code would be:

ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

---

Note that `ArrayList<double>` can not be used in Java (currently) since `double` is a **primitive data-type**. You therefore need to use its wrapper class `Double`. However Java is able to automatically convert `double` to `Double` and vice versa whenever needed. This process is called **auto-boxing** (or -unboxing).

---

What you are currently doing, i.e. not identifying the object type, is called **raw-type**.

It is an artifact of the time where generics where not available in Java (below version 1.5). The usage is **strongly discouraged**.

Even if you want to put everything inside you should use at least `List<Object>` instead of just `List`.

Comment: You cannot use keywords for generics, it would be: `ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();`. Also, you always have to identify the object type.

Comment: The generic usage of **primitive datatypes** is **not** possible in Java (at least currently). You need to use the wrapper classes `Double` etc. instead.

Comment: Oh ok! Sorry about that!

Comment: '*you need to identify*' - Well, one can use it without, this is called **raw-type**. However the usage of *raw-types* is **strongly discouraged**, it's just there for downwards compatibility.

Comment: @Zabuza, just out of curiosity, why would one use a raw-type?

Comment: @JasperHsu If you need to work with versions **below Java 1.5**, before generics came to Java. Other than that there is no scenario since `List<Object>` essentially does the same as `List`. All modern IDEs will warn about the usage of raw-types.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the type of array list. else it will be a default Object type.

```
 ArrayList<Double> numbers = new ArrayList();
```

else cast the retrieved value to double.

```
double highest = (double)numbers.get(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double highest = (double)numbers.get(0);
       for(int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++){
           int compare = Double.compare(highest, (double)numbers.get(i));
       if(compare < 0){
          highest = (double)numbers.get(i);
        }

        System.out.print(highest+"   ");
       }
```